# constructor not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, alert

I have a simple object constructor that my testing function does not pass properly.

Here is the constructor:

```
function objCon(name,count) { //object constructor
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
}
```

Here is the testing function:

```
function testing() {
    var here = new objCon(n, 2);
    alert(here.name + ":" + here.count);
}
```

However, when I test it, I do not get any alert. I need to pass it to a larger function that will store objects in an array.

Comment: Where is `n` defined? Just show the whole code.

Comment: n is the value of the name property of here. n is passed as an argument to objCon which has the possible arguments name and count to create an object with the properties name and count. so: here.name === n.

Comment: According to this code, `n` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see a reference error in the console because:

```
    var here = new objCon(n, 2); // <-- n is not declared or otherwise initialised
```

So pass a suitable value for n, e.g.

```
    var here = new objCon('Fred', 2);
```

or maybe:

```
    var n = 'Fred';
    var here = new objCon(n, 2);
```

Also, the first letter of a constructor name is usually capitalised to show it's a constructor, so:

```
function ObjCon() {
  ...
}
...
    var here = new ObjCon('Fred', 2);
...
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is case-sensitive.

```
var here = new ObjCon(n, 2);
               ^
```

You've defined your function as `objCon` but used a capital `O` there instead.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer could be constructed from all the bits and pieces above,
but the most important thing that you've missed is that you've only *defined* testing,
you haven't actually *invoked it*.

In other words, the function *testing* now exists, but you haven't told it to run.

```
function objCon(name,count) { //object constructor
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
}

function testing() {
    var here = new objCon('n', 2); // modified to insert a string. n doesn't already refer to anything, but 'n' is a valid string that can be passed in as an argument.

    alert(here.name + ":" + here.count);
}
```

and now to invoke it:

```
testing();
```

and you will get your alert.

Comment: thank you, i was using window.onload for a browser app

Comment: "Instantiation" is creating a new *instance* of something. Calling a method is not creating an instance of it; you're just "invoking" it.

Comment: Thanks, good catch @Cory, I edited the answer to reflect my mistake. "instantiate" --> "invoke".